# grabbing a google map link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension where it would grab the link of any website and send it off to localStorage. I know how to grab a link from the onmibox. But, in the case of Google Maps, the "real" link is never shown. So far, I have not found anything that could help me.

How would I be able to accomplish this? I don't have much experience in Javascript, but any help would be appreciated. If you need a better explanation, please ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Google Maps, the link to the actual page is available in an `<a id="link">` element.

In a Content script, getting the target of the link is pretty straightforward:

```
var link = document.getElementById('link').href;
```